# How can I append with JavaScript to a page, html that contains attribute definitions enclosed in single quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have some JS code that creates on the fly some HTML elements. Let's say something like this:

```
var html = '<a href="#" class="example">Some content</a>';
$(whateverselector).append(html);
```

As you can see jQuery is used. I am trying to do the following: I am generating some html elements and I want that on this specific elements I add attributes that are enclosed in single quotes.

```
var someOption = '<a href="#" data-options=\'{"maxWidth": 100, "maxHeight": 100}\'></a>';
$(whateverselector).append(someOption);
```

What happens is that the single quote is replaced by double quotes in the final DOM after jQuery is adding the element to the page. So it looks like this:

```
<a href="#" data-options="{"maxWidth": 100, "maxHeight": 100}"></a>
```

The issue is that another (independent) library is reading this values and it is not parsing them correctly (as an object) with the double quotes.

How can I make this attribute display with single quotes inside the DOM? Probably this is an issue from the append method in jQuery. Vanilla JS solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: I am afraid that it is the behavior of browser to use double quotes `"`. I tried to create a simple tag in chrome -> `<div class='hopa'>example</div>` but it changes it to double quotes. Does this independent library parse the DOM elements directly or do you have some control over them. If you have some controll, you could do some string parsing and replace double quotes for single quotes. Note that it can be quite dangerous if you data-options will contain quotes themselves...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens is that the single quote is replaced by double quotes in the final DOM after jQuery is adding the element to the page.

You're missing the difference between *markup* and the live structure that is the DOM.

Markup (HTML in this case) is a *textual representation* of the elements. Once it's parsed and the elements are created, they're objects in a tree (the document). The quotes on attribute values are a **markup** thing; they don't exist once the markup is parsed.

For instance, these have **identical** results:

```
$("whatever").append("<a href='#'>...</a>");
$("whatever").append('<a href="#">...</a>');
```

There's no difference, at all, in the resulting `a` element in the DOM.

Browsers showing you the DOM (for instance, Inspect Element in the dev tools) are showing you a representation of the DOM. They can show the attribute values however they choose; most in my experience show them in double quotes, but they could use single quotes if they liked. It has nothing to do with the markup (if any) that was parsed to create those elements.

> The issue is that another (independent) library is reading this values and it is not parsing them correctly (as an object) with the double quotes.

I suspect you're misinterpreting what's going wrong. But if you're not, the library in question is simply broken. Proof:

```js
var someOption = '<a href="#" data-options=\'{"maxWidth": 100, "maxHeight": 100}\'></a>';
$(document.body).append(someOption);
var options = JSON.parse($("a").attr("data-options"));
console.log(options.maxWidth, options.maxHeight); // 100, 100
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is probably confusing when the "inspect" in chrome for instance "shows" it like `<a href="#" data-options="{&quot;maxWidth&quot;: 100, &quot;maxHeight&quot;: 100}"></a>` with the `&quot;` visually as a double quote, but this is the correct answer from what I see here.  Note if you do a "copy outer" which is what I did you get the above which is revealing.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Yeah. Both Shrome and Firefox *display* it in the DOM inspector as `data-options="{"maxWidth": 100, "maxHeight": 100}"` with the outermost quotes in a different color to the ones within the value, which isn't as clear as one would like the but the various options are all to varying degrees as bad as each other. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data1) or even the [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) functions of jQuery:

```
var someOption = $('<a href="#" data-options=""></a>');
someOption.data('options' , '{"maxWidth": 100, "maxHeight": 100}');
// OR: someOption.attr('data-options' , '{"maxWidth": 100, "maxHeight": 100}');
$(whateverselector).append(someOption);
```

Comment: There's no need, what the OP is doing is fine.

Comment: Also note that `data` is **not** an accessor for `data-*` attributes. It's both less and more than that. If the library is looking for a `data-options` attribute, `.data('options', ...)` will not work.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this:

```
<body>

    <h1>Title</h1>

    <p class="text"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var someOption = "<a href=\"#\" data-options=\"{'maxWidth': 100, 'maxHeight': 100}\">Some text</a>";
            $(".text").append(someOption);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: They could, but then the options wouldn't be valid JSON anymore. Moreover, there's no need to, what they're doing is fine.